# Meaning of $H_0(X) = \tilde H_0(K)\oplus\Bbb Z $ and its Proof

Tags: homology-cohomology

While I am reading the wikipedia page of Homology and Reduced-homology groups, I've ran into following equation.

> $H_0(X) = \tilde  H_0(K)\oplus\Bbb Z $

For given X, which is defined to be simplical complex a priori, $H_0(X)$ defines the free abelian group with the connected components of X as generators, which means if there's a given simplical complex, $H_0(X)$ fills out that boundary to be **solid**. This is what I understood.

Now, back to our equation, especially the LHS, then there's a reduced form with the notation *tilde* and $\Bbb Z$, what does $\oplus$ refer to?

Any hint to proceed my understanding?

And If the proof is given, the following would be much more helpful to understand what the equal signs means.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proving that $H_0(X)=\tilde{H_0}(X)\oplus\mathbb{Z}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1234541/proving-that-h-0x-tildeh-0x-oplus-mathbbz)

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Could you teach me the name or definition of operator $\bigoplus$?

Comment: $\oplus$ stands for the [direct sum of abelian groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum#Direct_sum_of_abelian_groups)

Comment: Direct sum of modules ($\Bbb Z$-modules in this case). You may want to read homology from an actual book. Allen Hatcher's has a rather extensive treatment of the subject and it is available for download from the author's webpage.